# Как указывать исключения при статической линковке CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, линковка

Как в CMake указывать исключения при статической линковке библиотек в проекте. Т.е указать конкретную библиотеку как динамическую.
Нужно это т.к программа падает при статической линковки glibc(платформа x64_Linux).

Мой CMakeLists.txt выглядит так:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")

project (MyProject)

add_executable (MyProject main.cpp)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(cpr GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libcpr/cpr.git GIT_TAG f4622efcb59d84071ae11404ae61bd821c1c344b) # the commit hash for 1.6.2
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpr)

target_link_libraries(MyProject PRIVATE cpr::cpr)
```

Comment: ¿Может для начала стоит разобраться, почему падает?

Comment: @user7860670 , Я новичок, и мне сложно верно идентифицировать проблему. Я использовал gdb, благодаря чему понял на каком именно этапе падает работающая программа. Исходя из информации в интернете это связано с glibc, он не предназначен для статической связи и фактически во время работы вызывает динамическую библиотеку libnss и софт падает. 
glibc использует библиотека, которую я подключаю, по этому я не могу от него отказаться.

Comment: Тогда стоит задать новый вопрос, посвящённый именно этой проблеме. Обычно для статической линковки не требуется делать какие-то исключения.

Comment: @user7860670 А это в целом возможно, имеется ввиду исключение при статической линковке?